# How to avoid null values ​in a stream

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

We are in the case where we have a corrupted data X in the list, and where the presence of this corrupted data X prevents an operation on Y data of the same type as X. . This isn't normal, and we must shield the code so that the presence of the corrupt data X does not block the use of other valid data.

I used Optional with an operation filter, for filter if the name is null we skip.

```
     Personne personne = null;
     String name= personne.getName();
     try {
        Optional<Personne> abstractPersonne= 
      APIPersonne.getAllPersonne(currentPersonne.getMethod())
                                                            .stream()
                                                            .filter(e -> e.getName() != null && e.getName().equals(name))
                                                            .findAny();
  if (abstractPersonne.isPresent())
    personne= abstractPersonne.get();
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the test of (e-> e.getName != null) ?

Comment: Make sure it's not `null` and you can avoid it. If it can be `null` then you must check it unless you face an NPE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reverse the condition, if you are sure that the variable "name" is null safe. For example instead of

```
e.getName().equals(name)
```

use

```
name.equals(e.getName())
```

Comment: This the problem, the name i dont know if is null safe

Comment: @Rodik notice the logic: if `name` is `null`, then `abstractPersonnel` will be `Optional.empty`, which implies that `personnel` will have the value of `null`. 

So, after this line `String name= personne.getName();`, you can do a null-check:
`if (name == null) return;`

Now, you are sure that `name` is **not null**. So, you can safely reverse the condition as per @Harshal Khachane's recommendation

Answer (score 2):

Invert the condition: `name.equals(e.getName())`

```
.filter(e -> name.equals(e.getName()))
```

Comment: How does this answer *Is there a way to avoid the test of (e-> e.getName != null) ?*?

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the **Optional.ofNullable(*T*)** like this

- check the value is not null
- check with your string (list value and your desired string are equals or not )

```
Optional<Personne> abstractPersonne = APIPersonne
                    .getAllPersonne(currentPersonne.getMethod())
                    .stream()
                    .filter(e -> Optional.ofNullable(e).isPresent()  && e.getName().equals(name))
                    .findAny();
            if (abstractPersonne.isPresent())
                personne= abstractPersonne.get();
```